# getPlainBody Javascript

Tags: concatenation

Concatenate inbound email messages into a single google document each week and share that document via email. Inbound messages would be filtered into to a specific gmail label as a means of identifying them.  A follow-on enhancement would be to lookup the name of the person submitting the request based on the inbound email address in a google contact and add that to the messages concatenated into the google doc.